# ding finPGI compiler on Ubuntu

Tags: pgi

How check if PGI compiler and what version is installed on Ubuntu?
I have checked pgcc -⁠V and pgcc -⁠V but commands were not find. Maybe it means it was not installed properly.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the PGI compilers? (they don't come with Ubuntu by default)  If not, you can download the free Community Edition here: https://www.pgroup.com/products/community.htm

If they are installed, did you include the PGI bin directory in your PATH?

Note, installation instructions, including setting your PATH, can be found here: https://www.pgroup.com/resources/docs/18.7/x86/pgi-install-guide/index.htm#install-linux-pgi